# If $x \geq 2$ prove that $\sum_{ n \leq x} \frac{1}{\phi(n)} = \mathcal{O}(\log(x))$

Tags: number-theory, summation, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, totient-function

If $x \geq 2$ prove that $\sum_{ n \leq x} \frac{1}{\phi(n)} = \mathcal{O}(\log(x))$.

This problem is from Apostol's analytic number theory book in the chapter 3 exercises. I am stuck on this problem as I am simply not sure how to do it.

I know from the previous chapters that the following relation exists

$$\phi(n) = \sum_{d \mid n}\mu(d) \frac{n}{d}$$

So I have $\sum_{n \leq x} \phi(n) = \sum_{n \leq x} \sum_{d \mid n}\mu(d) \frac{n}{d}$, where $\mu(d)$ is the Möbius function.

Can anyone offer some information on how to proceed or use this relation?

Comment: are you sure there is no typo?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I have taken a picture of the exercise: http://i.imgur.com/BBtjSWJ.png See problem 10.

Comment: ah ok, that makes way more sense

Comment: Let $f(n) = \frac{1}{n}$. Write $\frac{1}{\varphi} = f \ast g$ and use some techniques to compute the summatory function of a convolution. Or use part b) of exercise 9 and the Abel sum formula.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for commenting. I am unfamiliar with what "the summatory function of a convolution" actually means. I'm looking in the previous chapters to see if I missed that.

Comment: The summatory function of $h$ is $H(x) := \sum\limits_{n \leqslant x} h(n)$. If $h$ is the Dirichlet convolution of two other functions, there are some techniques that can make the computation of $H(x)$ easier. But perhaps those haven't been treated at that point. In which case, exercise 9 b) + Abel deals with things.

Answer (score 6):

It is actually simpler to prove first that $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{n}{\varphi(n)}=O(x)$ then apply summation by parts.

$$ \sum_{n\leq x}\frac{n}{\varphi(n)} = \sum_{n\leq x}\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1}\leq \frac{\pi^2}{6}\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} $$
but we have
$$ \sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{1}{d} = \sum_{d\leq x}\frac{1}{d}\left\lfloor\frac{x}{d}\right\rfloor = O(x)$$

as mentioned in the comments. If we apply summation by parts,

$$ \sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{\varphi(n)} = \sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{n}{\varphi(n)} = O\left(\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{1}{n}\right) = O(\log n)$$
easily follows.

Comment: You meant $\sum_n \frac{\sigma(n)}{n}n^{-s} = \zeta(s)\zeta(s+1)$ behaving like $\zeta(2) \zeta(s)$ implying that $\sum_{n \le x} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = O(\sum_{n \le x} 1) = O(x)$

Comment: @user1952009: that's the same up to translation. I am applying the Tauberian theorem.

Comment: yes but then the pole is at $s=2$

Comment: and $\frac{\sigma(n)}{n} = \sum_{d | n} \frac{1}{d}$ so that $\sum_{n \le x}\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}  = \sum_{d\le x} \frac{1}{d} \lfloor x/d \rfloor = O(x)$

Comment: No you are wrong. What matters for the asymptotic of $\sum_{n < x} \frac{a_n}{n}, a_n \ge 0$ is the abscissa of convergence and the "dominating singularity" of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}$, not its analytic continuation at $s=1$. The two are the same if $a_n = O(1)$ but this is not the case here.

Comment: @user1952009: all right, fixed.