# Prove that $\sum_{x\le{n}}\frac{1}{\varphi{(x)}} = \mathcal{O}(ln{}(n))$

Tags: number-theory

So I've never proved anything like this before, as this is my first time working with big O notation. Upon being presented with it, I decided to use induction. From what I understand of this, the equation means that $\exists k \mid \forall x \sum_{x\le{n}}\frac{1}{\varphi{(x)}} \le k\cdot\ln{}n$. So, I was going to show that this is true for $n = 2$, the base case here, and then assume its true for all $n$, then prove for $n+1$. My work was as follows for the inductive step.

$$\sum_{x\le{n+1}}\frac{1}{\varphi{(x)}} \le k\cdot\ln{}(n+1)$$
$$\sum_{x\le{n}}\frac{1}{\varphi{(x)}}+\frac{1}{\varphi{(n+1})} \le k\cdot\ln{}(n+1)$$
$$k*\ln{}(n+1)+\frac{1}{\varphi{(n+1})} \le k\cdot\ln{}(n+1)$$

At this point, we note that $\varphi{(n)}$ has a lower bound of $\frac{n}{\ln{}\ln{}(n)}$. Hence, our left hand side will maximize with this value, so we can write

$$k\cdot\ln{}(n+1)+\frac{\ln{}\ln{}(n+1)}{n+1} \le k\cdot\ln{}(n+1)$$

Raising e to each side of the equation and simplifying yields

$$\sqrt[n+1]{\ln{}(n+1)} \le \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^k$$

At this point, I don't know what to do. Am I going about this right, or am I completely off base?

Edit: While the initial question is the same as the one this was tagged as a duplicate of, the question being asked here is whether induction is a valid approach to solving this problem without using the methods discussed in the other post.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299177/if-x-geq-2-prove-that-sum-n-leq-x-frac1-phin-mathcalo-log/2299194 I don't think there is any easier way

Comment: From $\frac{1}{\varphi(n)} = \mathcal{O}(\frac{\ln \ln n}{n})$ you won't get anything better than $\sum_{n < x } \frac{1}{\varphi(n)} =\mathcal{O}((\ln \ln x) (\ln x))$